# SQL equivalent to an active record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a query I have made that works well

```
Team.all.map do |team|
   message = CoachFee.find_one(team_id: team.id).team_price_explanation[:prices]
end
```

My 'team' class is simply

```
{
         :id => 1,
    :team_id => 6,
 :created_at => nil,
  :player_id => nil,
 :updated_at => nil,
    :user_id => 1417
}
```

The `team` class has a one to many relationship with the `CoachFee` class.

The only problem is that I have well over 300,000 database values of `CoachFee` in my application, and so running this can take forever. (well over 4 minutes).

Are there any `sql` gurus out there that know quickly how to replace `CoachFee.find_one(team_id: team.id)` from Active Record to SQL?

Much thanks to anyone in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide the relationships between `Team` and `CoachFee` e.g. is it `has_one :coach_fee` or `has_many :coach_fees`? Also what is `team_price_explanation`?

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky i should have added that in the first place. `team_price_explanation` actually calls a service that manages pricing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
CoachFee
  .where(id: CoachFee.select(CoachFee.arel_table[:id].minimum).group(:team_id))
  .map {|cf| cf.team_price_explanation[:prices]}
```

This will result in the following SQL

```
SELECT 
  coach_fees.*
FROM 
  coach_fees 
WHERE 
  coach_fees.id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      MIN(coach_fees.id) 
    FROM 
      coach_fees
    GROUP BY 
      coach_fees.team_id
  )
```